# Extracting numbers from a HTML string then append to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Hi i am trying to get just the numbers from a html string and append them to a URL which is then wrote to the page as a example:

```
<p id="catId">cat number 2301254187</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var itemId = document.getElementById('catId').innerHTML;
        var links = '<a href="http://www.test.com' + catId + '">Go to Catergory</a>';
        document.write(links);
```

Ive tried something like above which works but i get the whole of the contents of the p tag. Im pretty new to this and im guessing that regular expressions need to be used to extract the numbers only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right about needing to use a regular expression.

```
<p id="catId">cat number 2301254187</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var itemId = document.getElementById('catId').innerHTML.match(/\d+/);

    if (itemId.length) {
        var links = '<a href="http://www.test.com' + itemId[0] + '">Go to Catergory</a>';
        document.write(links);
    }
</script>
```

See the [`match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the numbers with a simple regex

```
var itemId = document.getElementById('catId').innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily, should the string always be `cat number NNNNNNNN`, you can use split.

```
var itemId = document.getElementById('catId').innerHTML.split(' ')[2];
```

Which splits the string into an array separated by spaces, and then displays the third element, which would be your number.